# local::lib and notest for Makefile.PL

Tags: perl, makefile

I have a Makefile.PL for which I want to install dependencies with a "notest" flag and using my local::lib home dir, but I can't get a grasp on the Makefile.PL options.

My Makefile.PL looks like this:

```
use inc::Module::Install;

name 'MyApp';
all_from 'lib/MyApp.pm';

requires 'Moose';
requires 'Catalyst::Runtime';
install_script glob('script/*.pl');
auto_install;
WriteAll;
```

I've noticed that evalling `local::lib` (which is already installed) into my bash session turns on some flags which will probably make dependencies install into local::lib, but I'm not sure and I've haven't tested it yet:

```
$ eval $(perl -Mlocal::lib)
$ perl -Mlocal::lib
export PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="$PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT:/home/user/perl5";
export PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base /home/user/perl5";
export PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/home/user/perl5";
export PERL5LIB="/home/user/perl5/lib/perl5/i686-linux:/home/user/perl5/lib/perl5:$PERL5LIB";
export PATH="/home/user/perl5/bin:$PATH";
```

But I'm not sure this will change the Makefile.PL deps behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to permanently apply the settings from the `eval` incantation, e.g. adding it to the `.bashrc`.

Yes, setting the `PERL_MM_OPT` variables changes the behaviour of ExtUtils::MakeMaker which is the foundation of Module::Install. See [INSTALL_BASE in ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://p3rl.org/ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker#INSTALL_BASE).

You need not change anything in your `Makefile.PL`.

---

```
PERL_CPANM_OPT=-n cpanm …
cpanp -i --skiptest …
```

Generally, skipping tests is not in your hand, but the user's. The [cpan client](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN/scripts/cpan) does not even allow this, only forcing an installation after a failed test step. If a user installs dependencies manually, he has the full control over each step and you cannot prevent him from running the test step at all.

I think you now need to explain what you want to achieve by wanting to prohibit testing.

Comment: neat, thanks, but how about making the dependencies install with "notest"?

Comment: I want to skip tests as "the user", even though I'm installing my own Makefile.PL. Skipping tests for deps in a Makefile.PL is something I wanted to know but never found the answer to. Sometimes I need to "make test" something quickly or simply test the Makefile.PL and waiting for dependencies to be tested is a pain...

Comment: Right, then you'll be happy with the [`-n` option for cpanminus](http://p3rl.org/cpanm#OPTIONS) as shown in the answer. It sounded very much like you wanted a general answer that applies to any user who'd want to install your module.